# Cannot display Oracle raster images using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, oracle-spatial

I am dealing with QGIS 2.2 and the plug-in Oracle spatial georaster.

Apparently the connection to the database can be made, as the raster images are listed once you press 'Connect', but when try to display them, either I see a black box or anything at all.

In theory my QGIS 2.2.0 has the GDAL version 1.10.1. I downloaded it using the OSGEO4w package for Windows.

Is there any way of testing where the problem might be?

Answer (score 2):

I never used QGIS for that, so I can only offer some generic advice about things to check:

- try starting QGIS from the command line. It may be that it reports some error or exception on the console
- If I am not mistaken, QGIS uses GDAL, and therefore the GDAL Georaster driver. Try setting the CPL_DEBUG environment variable to ON before running QGIS from the command line. This triggers a trace of everything that takes place, including the SQL statements sent to the database.
- Try using the georaster viewer that comes with Oracle - just to verify that it can see the raster.
- Try also using Oracle's Mapbuilder to check that it can see the raster(s).
- does your table contain multiple raster tiles ? Or just one single raster. Either way, did you create the spatial index on the raster footprints ?
- are your rasters properly georeferenced ?